# Detecting the use of + - " * in a string

Tags: php, strpos

Here is my test query:

```
if (strpos($q, '+') > 0 || strpos($q, '-') > 0 || strpos($q, '"') > 0 || strpos($q, '*') > 0) {

    print ("Advanced search operators are being used");

} else {

    print ("Advanced search operators are NOT being used"); 
}

$q = '-lavender' fails
$q = 'burn -lavender' passes
```

What am I doing wrong?  I would like to have it pass anytime a + or - is in the string at all.

Thanks

Comment: classic mistake: use `> -1` or `>= 0`

Comment: @goldenparrot Classic mistake use `!== false`

Comment: @PeeHaa classic mistake use `is_int(strpos($q, '+'))`

Comment: @webarto classic mistake use jquery

Comment: @Lusitanian not sure if sirius or trolling ;D

Answer (score 7):

`strpos()` returns `false` if it doesn't find the value, otherwise it returns the position beginning at `0`.

Your comparisons should check to see if the return value `!== false`:

```
if (strpos($q, '+') !== false || strpos($q, '-') !== false || strpos($q, '"') !== false || strpos($q, '*') !== false)
```

**OR**

You could use a `regular expression`:

```
preg_match('/[-+*"]+/', $q);
```

**UPDATE**

NikiC just brought [`strpbrk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php) to my attention, and it will work perfectly for you:

```
if (strpbrk ( $q, '-+*"') !== false)
```

It's the equivalent of that long `if` statement above.

Comment: Looks ok from here, but I'm not perfect with regex

Comment: @SomeKittens thanks, I verified it. Forgot to remove the `/`s in my regex tester.

Comment: @user1547257 please read my updated answer - `strpos` may still return the equivalent of 0 (`false`) if the substring isn't found.

Answer (score 3):

```
strpos($q, '+') !== false
```

`0` is a valid position, the first one.

**Edited after the enjoyable conversation with my SO comrades below.**

Comment: But `false` when cast to an integer is `0`, which according to you means it's been found in the first position.

Comment: Ahh good catch! Should be != false. Although "This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE."

Comment: `!= false` isn't enough either.

Comment: `!== false` is exactly what you should use. Why would you say it's not enough?

Comment: Because the function definition says it may also return non-Boolean values which evaluates to false. Not necessarily === false.

Comment: @databyss That means that it either returns `0` (for "occurs at start of string") or `false` (for "doesn't occur"). That's why you have to check for `!== false`.

Comment: @databyss it may return 0 (match found at start of string), which can evaluate to false if loosely checked (== or !=)... so !== false (strict check) is the way to go. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Oh lol, I'm dumb. I read that as a warning that it might return a non-Boolean false since it was in the Return Values section. Not that a valid result of 0 could be misinterpreted as FALSE. WHEEEEEEEE!

Answer (score 2):

In `-lavender`, strpos is returning `0` because it's finding `-` at the beginning of the string (or index `0`).

Try this:

```
strpos($q, '-') !== false
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$mystring = 'abc';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

`strpos` returns `false` if no match is found, or `0` if it is found at the start. To distinguish the two, use `===`.

However, it could be made easier:

```
if( preg_match('/[-+"*]/',$q)) {
    echo "Advanced search";
}
```

Comment: Don't `+` and `*` have to be escaped?

Comment: Not in a character class, they have no meaning there.

Comment: @Kolink you might want add a word boundary, although likely it is not necessary... http://rubular.com/r/08k7UIzLjh

Answer (score 0):

strpos returns the position of the character in the string; in the first test string, `'-lavender` the character is the first one.

In that case, strpos is returning 0, which is the first character. That evaluates to false, even though the string is found.

You need to do a boolean compare:

```
if (strpos($q, '-') !== false ...
```